# Function with lazy and non-lazy arguments

Tags: functions

Consider the function

```
Z[entropy_, beta_] := Sum[E^(entropy[[i, 2]] - beta entropy[[i, 1]])
   , {i, 1, Length[entropy]}]
```

where entropy is a list of pairs (e.g. E, S(E)). I will plot this as a function `beta`. Since the parameter "entropy" is fixed in the plot, I wound't need to expand the sum every time, which this function is doing. So, I could try (the difference is `=` instead of `:=`)

```
Z[entropy_, beta_] = Sum[E^(entropy[[i, 2]] - beta entropy[[i, 1]])
   , {i, 1, Length[entropy]}]
```

However, in this situation, because "entropy" is not defined, it will always return 0 (sum of 0 terms).

Ideally, I would like to write `Z[entropyA, beta]` (where `entropyA` is a list) and it return the sum expanded (lazy on beta), and when it is called as `Z[entropyA, 1.2]`, it returns the outcome of the calculation (i.e. it replaces beta by 1.2 on the sum).

Which brings me to my question: how can I define a function that is lazy on one parameter (e.g. `beta`), but not lazy on the other.

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind; is the `entropy` argument a list or an integer, and does your function have two or three arguments?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, fixed. The function was more complicated and I was trying to build a minimal example.

Comment: A compact definition: `Z[entropy_List, beta_] := Total[E^(#2 - beta #1) & @@@ entropy]`; this will not expand unless the first argument is manifestly a list.

Comment: Will you need to do symbolic manipulations on this function (which makes sense for a partition function, e.g. for computing the average form the derivative)?  Or do you only need to evaluate for numerical `beta`?

Answer (score 4):

```
z[entropy_][beta_] := 
  Sum[E^(entropy[[i, 2]] - beta entropy[[i, 1]]), {i, 1, 
    Length[entropy]}];

f = z[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];

f /@ Range@5

(* {2 E, 1 + 1/E^2, 1/E^5 + 1/E, 1/E^8 + 1/E^2, 1/E^11 + 1/E^3} *)
```

Avoid using uppercase initials for your own symbols, BTW...

This still evaluates the sum, of course. You can achieve the desired goal with your `Set` definition:

```
f=Z[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, beta];
```

Then use replacement for differing beta:

```
f/.beta->1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

What I think you are seeking:

```
z[entropy_List] := 
 beta \[Function] 
  Evaluate[Sum[E^(entropy[[i, 2]] - beta entropy[[i, 1]]), {i, 1, Length[entropy]}]]
```

Now:

```
z[{{9, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {4, 0}, {9, 5}}]
```

> ```
> Function[beta$, 
>  E^(1 - 9 beta$) + E^(5 - 9 beta$) + E^(4 - 3 beta$) + E^(6 - 3 beta$) + E^(-4 beta$)]
> ```